# Is $f$ a constant?

Tags: functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x + y) + f(x − y) = f(xy)$ for all $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$. Is $f$ constant?!

I do get that the function is an even function but I don't where to go forward from that? Can $f$ be zero btw ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Clearly $f$ satisfies this identity if it's identically $0$. Hint: what can you say when you set $y=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $y=0$, we see that $$2f(x)=f(0),$$
hence $f$ is constant. In particular, with $x=0$, we have $2f(0)=f(0)$, hence the constant must be $0$.